# 401 Unauthorized in OWA 2013 when login through AD FS

Tags: exchange, outlook, single-sign-on

I have an Exchange 2013 server setup to Single Sign-On through an AD FS setup. The whole workflow goes fine with the redirection to AD FS and after AD FS, a WS-Federation response is sent to OWA. However, I get an HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized when the response is posted to OWA. What can be the cause of this error?

I tried adding the signing certificates to the trusted stores and intermediate stores but they did not help. The link to the response being posted to OWA is below.

https://pastebin.com/6gXmrCNZ

Anything incorrect in the response or something I can do to solve this?

Comment: Did this work before?
In ADFS Management Console update the Federation metadata URLs and do an IIS reset on Exchange  server. Next, restart the ADFS service.

Comment: No. I am setting it up afresh. Restarted IIS and AD FS.

Comment: It may need to use network trace to check the request, and also need AD engineers’ help.

Comment: I can do a Fiddler trace of that. Any specific thing that I need to look at?

Comment: The whole connection.Did you deploy hybrid?